# how to develop chat module in the current application as Live Support?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a chat application. This application holds the records of the visitors, configure chat options, tracking of referrer page of the visitors. I want to include a chat module in this application. I also want to use this chat module to be used as Live Support for any website. There will be a link on the website for visitor to start a chat and chat window starts appearing. Please guide me how can I include this feature (adding links for Live Support on websites to start chat sessions ) as well as including chat module in my application. I am not asking about chating code, I am just asking about the way to implement my requirement. I know there are Areas in asp.net mvc. Can they be my first choice ?

Comment: Maybe you can use SignalR: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Comment: @`Areas` is an feature to introduce `Plugin` functionality. But, since  you are gonna re-use this `chat module`, I prefer writing a separate `library`. You can `just reference it` and use it.

Comment: Hi, I know about the SignalR and the way to use it. I am just asking how can I open popup on the website where I am providing Live Support ? Should I create seprate Chat App or should include module in the current app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SignalR](http://signalr.net):

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.

Example of chart application:

1. [Demo](http://philknows.net/SignalR/chat)
2. [Source](http://philknows.net/SignalR/Content/Source.zip)

`Chart module` should be the part of your main app, i think. If you've created a new app for `chart module`, as minimum, you will have problems with autorization. It will be a strange behavoir - request user login/pass when user opens chart window from your site (where he is already autorized).

Comment: Hi, I know about the SignalR and the way to use it. I am just asking how can I open popup on the website where I am providing Live Support ? Should I create seprate Chat App or should include module in the current app ?